# Upload Only Allowed FileTypes

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, upload, filesystems

i'm working on a form where user can upload, im using FreeASPUpload component.

Right now i can upload anything and that would cause major security issue on server. How can i restrict only specific file types. i only want users to upload ".doc", ".docx" and ".pdf" files.

**Here is the source code.**

```vbs
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% 
option explicit 
Response.Expires = -1
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600
Session.CodePage  = 65001
%>

<!-- #include file="UploadClass.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="ADOVBS.inc" -->

<%
Dim uploadsDirVar
uploadsDirVar = server.MapPath("Resumes_Uploaded") 

function OutputForm()
%>
<form name="frmSend" id="appform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" action="form.asp" onSubmit="return onSubmitForm();">
<input type="hidden" name="ApplicationForm" value="Insert" />
Name: <input type="text" name="name_insert" value="" size="30" />
<B>File names:</B><br>
File 1: <input name="attach1" type="file" size=35><br>
<br>
<input style="margin-top:4" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<%
end function

function TestEnvironment()
    Dim fso, fileName, testFile, streamTest
    TestEnvironment = ""
    Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if not fso.FolderExists(uploadsDirVar) then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not exist.</B><br>The value of your uploadsDirVar is incorrect. Open uploadTester.asp in an editor and change the value of uploadsDirVar to the pathname of a directory with write permissions."
        exit function
    end if
    fileName = uploadsDirVar & "\test.txt"
    on error resume next
    Set testFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, true)
    If Err.Number<>0 then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not have write permissions.</B><br>The value of your uploadsDirVar is incorrect. Open uploadTester.asp in an editor and change the value of uploadsDirVar to the pathname of a directory with write permissions."
        exit function
    end if
    Err.Clear
    testFile.Close
    fso.DeleteFile(fileName)
    If Err.Number<>0 then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not have delete permissions</B>, although it does have write permissions.<br>Change the permissions for IUSR_<I>computername</I> on this folder."
        exit function
    end if
    Err.Clear
    Set streamTest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    If Err.Number<>0 then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>The ADODB object <I>Stream</I> is not available in your server.</B><br>Check the Requirements page for information about upgrading your ADODB libraries."
        exit function
    end if
    Set streamTest = Nothing
end function

function SaveFiles
    Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey, strFileName, strFileType, oFSO, DelFile, fso

    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)

    ' If something fails inside the script, but the exception is handled
    If Err.Number<>0 then Exit function

     SaveFiles = ""
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    if (UBound(ks) <> -1) then
        SaveFiles = "<B>Files uploaded:</B> "
        for each fileKey in Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    SaveFiles = SaveFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & " (" & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).Length & "B) "

       next
    else
        SaveFiles = "No file selected for upload or the file name specified in the upload form does not correspond to a valid file in the system."
    end if
%>

<%
'=======================================================================================
' CONNECT DATABASE
'=======================================================================================
Dim objConn, objRs, InsCom, InsName
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConn.open"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="& server.MapPath("db/Job_database.mdb") &";Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=False"

If Upload.Form("ApplicationForm") = "Insert" Then
Set InsCom=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
InsCom.ActiveConnection=objConn

InsName = Trim(Upload.Form("name_insert"))
InsName = replace(InsName,"'","''")

InsCom.CommandText = "Insert into applications(aname)Values(?)"
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@name_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsName)

InsCom.Execute

End If  

Response.Redirect("success.asp")    
end function
%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Free ASP Upload 2.0</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
BODY {background-color: white;font-family:arial; font-size:12}
</style>
<script>
function onSubmitForm() {
    var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
    if (formDOMObj.attach1.value == "")
        alert("Please press the Browse button and pick a file.")
    else
        return true;
    return false;
}
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<br><br>
<div style="border-bottom: #A91905 2px solid;font-size:16">Upload files to your server</div>
<%
Dim diagnostics
if Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") <> "POST" then
    diagnostics = TestEnvironment()
    if diagnostics<>"" then
        response.write "<div style=""margin-left:20; margin-top:30; margin-right:30; margin-bottom:30;"">"
        response.write diagnostics
        response.write "<p>After you correct this problem, reload the page."
        response.write "</div>"
    else
        response.write "<div style=""margin-left:150"">"
        OutputForm()
        response.write "</div>"
    end if
else
    response.write "<div style=""margin-left:150"">"
    OutputForm()
    response.write SaveFiles()
    response.write "<br><br></div>"
end if

%>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have searched alot and found only a few solutions, but they doesn't work on my end.
here is the most recent changes i made, but the file doesn't gets deleted from the server after file uploaded.

**Here is the code**

```vbs
function SaveFiles
    Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey, strFileType, oFSO

    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)

    ' If something fails inside the script, but the exception is handled
    If Err.Number<>0 then Exit function

    SaveFiles = ""
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    if (UBound(ks) <> -1) then
        SaveFiles = "<B>Files uploaded:</B> "
        for each fileKey in Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
            strFileType = Left(Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).ContentType,5)
            if strFileType = ".doc" and ".docx" and ".pdf" Then
                SaveFiles = SaveFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & " (" & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).Length & "B) "
            else
                DelFile = DelFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & ","
            end if          
        next

        %>
<%

    else
        SaveFiles = "The file name specified in the upload form does not correspond to a valid file in the system."
    end if
    if DelFile <> "" Then
         DelFile = left(DelFile,len(DelFile)-1)
         set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         if inStr(DelFile,",") > 0  then
              arrDelete = split(DelFile,",")
              for i = 0 to UBound(arrDelete)
                   oFSO.DeleteFile uploadsDirVar & arrDelete(i)
              next
         else
             oFSO.DeleteFile uploadsDirVar & DelFile
         end if
         oFSO.close
         set oFSO = nothing
    end if
```

[FreeASPUpload documentation](http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/documentation.asp) doesn't help.

Comment: why doesn't the file get deleted? You should state if you're getting errors on your code, etc..

Comment: File uploads any ways, i don't receive any errors...

Comment: You must have an error somewhere. Disable all `On Error Resume Next` lines on your code, to find out where the code is breaking...

Comment: There is only 1 `on error resume next` here `fileName = uploadsDirVar & "\test.txt"
    on error resume next
    Set testFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, true)` i believe this function has nothing to do with file saving and or deleting. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: check the code in your include files... They could be setting `On Error Resume Next` globally...

Comment: On [UploadClass.asp](http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/viewsource.asp) i found `on error resume next` and commented all the code after it and uploaded a file then browser returns **The connection was reset**

Comment: That seems like a network error, it has nothing to do with the code you're developing...

Comment: I think this is beyond what FreeASPUpload can do.  Obviously you can read the file extensions, which will probably be enough, but beyond that it can't check the content type of the file.  For file uploads it's worth looking at .net solutions if your server supports it.  I'm not saying you should rewrite your entire site in .net, but you can have a single .net page which sits alongside your Classic pages to handle the upload and the accompanying database insert.  It isn't difficult, even if you've never really used .net http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Comment: Thank you John, as you can see i'm still learning the Classic ASP i don't think i can jump to a more advance language right now. but i'll try. i saw this tutorial before posting this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code, and it works as expected...

```vbs
function SaveFiles
    ' You forgot to declare the DelFile Variable
    Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey, strFileType, oFSO, DelFile

    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)

    ' If something fails inside the script, but the exception is handled
    If Err.Number<>0 then Exit function

    ' Set DelFile Variable to empty string
    DelFile = ""
    SaveFiles = ""
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    if (UBound(ks) <> -1) then
        SaveFiles = "<B>Files uploaded:</B> "
        for each fileKey in Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
            ' This does not return the file extension of the file uploaded
            ' strFileType = Left(Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).ContentType,5)
            strFileType = Mid(Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName, InstrRev(Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName, ".") + 1)
            ' This is an invalid if statement
            ' if strFileType = ".doc" and ".docx" and ".pdf" Then
            if strFileType = "doc" or strFileType = "docx" or strFileType = "pdf" Then
                SaveFiles = SaveFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & " (" & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).Length & "B) "
            else
                ' The var DelFiles does not exist
                'DelFile = DelFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & ","
                DelFile = DelFile & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & ","
            end if
        next
    else
        SaveFiles = "The file name specified in the upload form does not correspond to a valid file in the system."
end if
if DelFile <> "" Then
     DelFile = left(DelFile,len(DelFile)-1)
     set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     if inStr(DelFile,",") > 0  then
          arrDelete = split(DelFile,",")
          for i = 0 to UBound(arrDelete)
               ' this is wrong, you're missing a backspace
               ' oFSO.DeleteFile uploadsDirVar & arrDelete(i)
               oFSO.DeleteFile uploadsDirVar & "\" & arrDelete(i)
          next
     else
         ' this is wrong, you're missing a backspace
         ' oFSO.DeleteFile uploadsDirVar & DelFile
         oFSO.DeleteFile(uploadsDirVar & "\" & DelFile)
     end if
         ' This is an invalid statement
         ' oFSO.close
         set oFSO = nothing
    end if
end function
```

**Note:** Your code was full of errors... I tried my best to explain where they were and what they were, but that's no substitute for learning how to properly debug asp code. You should try to get a grasp on how to debug asp, before attempting to integrate my code in your solution.

Comment: @basto.serdio i really appreciate your help, Im really a beginner in ASP and im trying to learn it well. I only ask for help when im stuck and when i can't figure out anything else.

I tried your code and it gives a 500 - Internal Server error. **Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A03F6) Expected 'End'
/test/form.asp, line 136**

Comment: Thanks, Shadow Wizard. 1 Question though since you showed up :D
Is this form secure to deploy to web server or its needed some other security fixes too?

Comment: What kind of security issues are you afraid of? The code works, but except for the part of saving the file to disk it doesn't have any error checking in it... It's considered best practice to hide the errors away from potential users/hackers...

Comment: If someone made a very huge **PDF, doc or docx** file this could be a problem. and if someone uploaded a file with same name then it will replace the other file. these things also concern me

Comment: @yaqoob well you could restrict file-size. you can check this with JavaScript / jQuery before the Upload itself. also why do you save all  files in the same location? you could prevent overwrites by creating subdirectories

Comment: @Vogel612 Javascript will only validate from Client-Side which can be tricked by disabling JS in any browser but i'm doing it. About file storing, the upload component has defined the storage path in this variable `uploadsDirVar = Server.MapPath("Resumes_Uploaded")` How can i move the duplicate file into sub directory?

Comment: @yaqoob in general you can require JavaScript using the noscript tag. also you can simply use the FSO to create a subdirectory like: `fso.createFolder("subdirectory")` and then change the Write to Disk Directory (when you encounter a duplicate).